# How do I change my name in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

Many people have told me that I have to complete a route before being capable of changing my name, but I don't truly want to wait that long. My friend took control of my PC and messed up my name. I just want to know how to change it so I can not play as "LEzLIE". Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oorLyWyYRE8) video the steps to change your name (using config files):

1. Go to your start menu and enter %appdata%
2. From the folder this takes you to go back one
3. Follow this path: *Local/Undertale*
4. Open the Undertale config file
5. Go to down to Name="Current Name"
6. Change Current Name to the name that you want (in quotations!!!)
7. Save it
8. Go back to the Undertale folder
9. Open file 9
10. Change the first line to the name that you want (the same as the one in the Undertale config file!)
11. Save it
12. Open file 0
13. Repeat steps 10 and 11 for this file.
14. Open Undertale (Game) and press continue.

Don't change the numbers in these folders! You risk resetting your game!

Answer (score 0):

One way is deleting the save. I did that when I restarted my accadential genocide run. Or @Reflexive 's way if you wanna keep your save.