# How can I rename in Undertale on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, undertale

When I restart the game, I want a New name other than "Happy". Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change my name in Undertale?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345523/how-do-i-change-my-name-in-undertale)

Comment: This post originally had the xbox-one tag, which was removed in an edit, but seeing that the linked duplicate is a solution for PC, I reintroduced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option one: Complete the True Pacifist ending, and then select True Reset on the main menu. You will be prompted for a new name.

Option two: Erase your [save data](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/games-apps/game-setup-and-play/cloud-game-saves-faq) (even if you've already done an in-game reset, *Undertale* still keeps some data around, including the name you chose). This will completely clear out all progress you have made, and make the game "like new."

Comment: I guess XBox being more stingent on where your save might be, if you delete the save completely it will delete it completely, and not leave some small things behind that let the game know you've reset.

Comment: @Fredy31: Technically, this works just as well on PC or other consoles (the PC version does not make any unusually concerted effort to protect or hide itself from tampering). However, if you open up the save directory in, say, explorer.exe, and futz with it, Steam will see your save as corrupt and automatically restore it from backup, so you have to disable cloud backups if you want to do that.